# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object Facebook Array fetching image from object_id

Tags: php, facebook, api

i have projects to retrieve data from social media, fb ig twit etc.

And now i'm trying to get one-element-array(picture) but it went wrong. and idk what is the problem with Undefined variable even if i used isset already, it should be defined well enough.

could somebody explain it to me and give me some good example to understand?

this is my code and the cencored image of the result.

```
$page_id =xx;
$access_token =xx;

$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/posts?limit=5&access_token='.$access_token);

$fbdata = json_decode($json_object);

foreach ($fbdata->data as $post ){
    if(isset($post->object_id) == true){
        $posts .= '<p>Object_id :' . $post->object_id . '</p>';
        $object_id= $post->object_id;
        $json_img = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$object_id.'?fields=images&access_token='.$access_token);
        $fbimg = json_decode($json_img);
        foreach ($fbimg as $imageList ){
            $posts .= $imageList[0] -> source;
        }
    }

    if(isset($post->story) == true){
        $posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->story . '</a></p>';  
    }
    if(isset($post->created_time) == true){
    $created_time = "$post->created_time";
    $date_source = strtotime($created_time);
    $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_source);
        $posts .= '<p>' .$timestamp . '</p>';
    }
    if(isset($post->picture) == true){
        $posts .= '<img src="' . $post->picture . '">';
    }   
    if(isset($post->message) == true){
        $posts .= '<p>' . $post->message . '</p>';
    }
    if(isset($post->link) == true){
        $posts .= '<p>' . $post->link . '</p>';
    }
}
$posts .= '<br>';
echo $posts ;
```

got this result
[image: Cencored Result Image]

a little explain what this about, i succeed to retrieve picture from `object_id` and `object_id` it self but it shows some errors with message:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

from this line

```
$posts .= $imageList[0] -> source;
```

and the other error message is

> Notice: Undefined variable: posts

from this line

```
$posts .= '<p>Object_id :' . $post->object_id . '</p>';
```

actually i can set `error_reporting(0);` in top of the php. but i just want to know why, and could it slow me down to retrieving data from facebook?

Comment: You need to go learn how one does a little basic debugging. In your code, you are suppressing possible error messages, and you are performing no error checking at all - you just _assume_ everything went well, when in fact it didn’t. So start by looking at what return you actually got from the API.

Comment: @CBroe i did a var_dump, and it went good. so it's not assuming anymore right? yea, about debugging it's true, i'm not that good. From the code above, do i have something wrong at debugging?

Comment: Of what? Show us the result (edit your question.) // As for the error handling (or rather, lack thereof) – you don’t care if file_get_contents is successful, you don’t care if the result of that can actually be decoded as JSON … And that perhaps not every post that you get actually _has_ images attached to it isn’t something you did consider?

Comment: the code is not finished yet, i stop because this error messages. indeed after this is ok i will do some "if else" for image. @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

i just know whats wrong with my code,
that just like this to end the pain.

```
$posts = '';
foreach ($fbdata->data as $post ){

if(isset($post->object_id) == true){
    $posts .= '<p>Object_id :' . $post->object_id . '</p>';
    $object_id= $post->object_id;
        $json_img = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$object_id.'?fields=images&access_token='.$access_token);
        $fbimg = json_decode($json_img);
        foreach ($fbimg as $imageList ){
            if(isset($imageList) ==  true){     
                if(is_array($imageList) ){
                    $posts .= $imageList[0] -> source;
                    $facebookPicture = $imageList[0] -> source;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

> to kill the question number 2, i just define the $posts into a empty
>   variable to define who it is.

```
$posts = '';
```

> to kill the question number 1, i'm doing is_array function to check
>   the existance of array number of 'something' inside of the nested
>   array